# Was Chrysostom mistaken about the cessation of charismatic gifts in the late 4th century?

Tags: church-history, church-fathers, spiritual-gifts, cessationism, john-chrysostom

John Chrysostom (AD 347-407), while commenting on 2 Thessalonians 2:7, writes about how some in his day thought the prevalence of the full range of charismatic gifts functioned to restrain the coming of the man of lawlessness.

He writes:

> Some indeed say, the grace of the Spirit, but others the Roman empire,
> to whom I most of all accede. Wherefore? Because if he meant to say
> the Spirit, he would not have spoken obscurely, but plainly, that even
> now the grace of the Spirit, that is the gifts, withhold him. And
> otherwise he ought now to have come, if he was about to come when the
> gifts ceased; for they have long since ceased. But because he said
> this of the Roman empire, he naturally glanced at it, and speaks
> covertly and darkly. For he did not wish to bring upon himself
> superfluous enmities, and useless dangers. (Homily 4 on Second
> Thessalonians)

In examining the [patristic record](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0913573094), his observation seems to be in error at least for the first three centuries. However, is it possible that a full range distribution of charismatic gifts ceased sometime in the late fourth century? If so, what are the different theories accounting for such a decline?

Comment: Related questions:  [Did any early Church Fathers record the event of the ceasing of spiritual gifts?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/59538/50422), [Is there any historical evidence that the supernatural gifts of the Spirit were still in operation after the apostolic age?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84305/50422)

Comment: I think if the question is edited to focus fully on Chrysostom, then it will not be a duplicate. Up-voted +1.

Comment: According to your own source, *a Church which is strongly charismatic up until around **AD 200***; in other words, a century and a half before Chrysostom's birth, and two before his death.

Comment: The phrase “has long ceased” is subject to lots of interpretation. For example, the __________(fill in the blank) has long ceased in the mainline churches. How long is long? 20 years ago?